# Python Pandas: covariance between 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, covariance

I've read few posts on the topic but none were totally satisfying - for me
say I have a DF 'A'

```
CG2 CG1 X   Y   Z
1   1   5   4   1    
3   1   6   7   2    
1   1   9   2   5   
3   2   4   9   3    
1   2   8   5   6    
3   2   3   6   7
```

I am trying to bet a new DF 'B' with the covariances between X and Z by ['CG1','CG2']
My best effort was

```
B= A.groupby(['CG1','C2'],as_index=True)[['X','Z']].cov()
```

DF 'B' is like (cov values are dummy :-):

```
index       X      Z

(1,1,'X')  2.3     0

...
```

I was expecting more something like

```
CG1  CG2   X   Z

1     1    2.3 0

...
```

any hints for me ?

Cheers
apologies for the poor presentation of the dummy data

Comment: You can also use `B = A.groupby(['CG1','CG2'])['X','Z'].cov()`, but I think problem is you use old version of pandas. Last is `0.19.2` and check it by `print (pd.show_versions())`

Comment: Thanks Jezrael - I didn't think of that> I'll give it a shot and revert back to you. Cheers!!

Comment: I think the best is update pandas to last version, because it seems is bug.

Comment: well Jezrael it seesm I do have cPandas version 0.19.2

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.6.0.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 7
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 44 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en
LOCALE: None.None

pandas: 0.19.2
nose: 1.3.7
pip: 9.0.1
setuptools: 27.2.0
Cython: 0.25.2
numpy: 1.11.3
scipy: 0.18.1
statsmodels: 0.6.1
xarray: None
IPython: 5.1.0
sphinx: 1.5.1
...

Comment: Super, and now it works perfect, right?

Comment: sorry forgot that one: it doesn't I'm afraid

Comment: Same problem? For me it works perfectly. After upgrade do you restart pc?

Comment: Ok that's weird. do you have the nice output

Comment: I'm using windows in case it matters

Comment: I'll try restart things up - I'll check on a colleague computer as well on Monday (Saturday here now)

Comment: maybe I'm asking too much: with .var or .mean 
B = A.groupby(['CG1','CG2'])['X','Z'].var()

Comment: sorry haven't finished :-)

Comment: again
B = A.groupby(['CG1','CG2'])['X','Z'].var()    I get 'CG1' and 'CG2' + mean or var in output.   With .cov I don't- I get an 'index' column with reference to CG1 and CG2 and X or Z, eg., {1,1,X)

Comment: So I have no idea how can help you.

Comment: no pb. thanks for the help anyway. cheers